# Creating a new Group of every appearence of FALSE

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is my df:

```
structure(list(a = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

It looks like this:

```
       a b
1  FALSE 1
2   TRUE 1
3   TRUE 1
4  FALSE 2
5   TRUE 2
6   TRUE 2
7   TRUE 2
8  FALSE 3
9   TRUE 3
10  TRUE 3
11  TRUE 3
```

In column a I got a lot of boolean values. I want to create a new group every time a new FALSE appears. The desired output is in column b. How can I archieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `cumsum(!df$a)`

Comment: wow, brilliant and easy solution. Also tried cumsum, but not negated ;-)